# Create a custom form control

Tags: excel

In order to give a better look to my form, I've designed complex textboxes and comboboxes, which involves a text box, a label and little labels which works as animated borders.

The group have some functions to create the animations in both `Enter` and `Exit` events.
Everything works fine, but I want to create a custom type of control, in order to create them easily (now, for each instance of the control I place, I need to draw the standard textbox, a label, two labels which works as lines, place them with utmost precision and, finally, set the enter and exit events).

Can I create my custom control, with all these parts, so that I would just drag my control and everything is already set?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create custom controls you need to use a real programming language like VB.NET (if you want to stick to some Visual Basic language) and create an ocx file. This can then be used as any onther control in your form. But be aware that only people who have this ocx installed on their computer can use your Excel file then. So I highly recomend to stick with the controls available by default. There is no way to build controls with Excel.